# I want to draw a line and fill it with a repeating image in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I don't need code, just a starting point. I have a drawing app on iPad where you draw a line from point a to point b. Between the 2 points the line is replaced with a repeating image.!

Comment: Here's the starting point: `CGPointMake(100, 50)`

Comment: @H2CO3 LOL, you really made my day ... ;-) Sorry OP ...

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to use a CGColor *Pattern*, then draw the line using that. You can use `CGColorCreateWithPattern` to create a color pattern.